# Reducing database query sizes in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm looking to reduce the my query size in laravel.

My query looks something like this (I shortened it, it's about 10 times this amount of lines):

```
$users = User::where("interface_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)
->orWhere("interface_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', 1)
->orWhere("web_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)
->orWhere("web_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', 1)                    
->orWhere("illustration_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)
->orWhere("illustration_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', 1)                   
->orWhere("brush_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)
->orWhere("brush_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', 1)                  
->orWhere("typography_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)
->orWhere("typography_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', 1)                 
->orWhere("identity_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)
->orWhere("identity_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', 1)                   
->orWhere("vector_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)
->orWhere("vector_art", '=', 1)->where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', 1)                 
->orderBy($orderByString, 'desc')
->paginate(1);
```

As you can see, it's a bit redundant.

For every art type, I'm looking to get users by the role of "2", if their commstatus is equal to "1" or "$unavailable".

At first, I tried to shorten it by not adding "role" or "commstatus" at the end of each "where" clause, and at the bottom writing another $users = $users::where("role", "=", "2"), for example, but I can't seem to be able to find the right syntax that.

Is there any way to shorten this query?

Comment: It looks like you've got a schema that violates the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) and needs to be restructured to have some degree of [data normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). With the right schema this query could be pretty simple.

Comment: Well, it works just fine, I just want to shorten it, I just can't seem to find syntax that works. I've tried finding something in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) that might help me, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I hope `$unavailableCheck` is not representing `NULL`.  If so, you have other troubles.

Comment: @tadman +1 for mentioning `Zero one infinity rule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have stated, your schema would likely benefit from refactoring towards normalization. However, I believe you can still refactor your existing query to be less redundant and more readable.

Laravel has the ability to handle [Advanced Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) which include `nested parameter groupings`. From the documentation:

> The Closure will receive a query builder instance which you can use to set the constraints that should be contained within the parenthesis group.

With that in mind, you should be able to refactor the query like this:

```
$users = User::whereIn('commstatus', [$unavailableCheck, 1])
    ->where('role', 2)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where("interface_art", 1)
            ->orWhere("web_art", 1)
            ->orWhere("illustration_art", 1)
            ->orWhere("brush_art", 1)
            ->orWhere("typography_art", 1)
            ->orWhere("identity_art", 1)
            ->orWhere("vector_art", 1);
    })
    ->orderBy($orderByString, 'desc')
    ->paginate(1);
```

That will create a SQL query that does:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
    WHERE commstatus IN ($unavailableCheck, 1)
    AND role = 2
    AND (interface_art = 1 OR illustration_art = 1 OR ... etc)
```

Comment: Congrats, you win!

Answer (score 4):

You certainly shouldn't need to duplicate `where('role', '=', 2)->where('commstatus', '=', $unavailableCheck)` for every single type of art, as they're effectively ANDed conditions; and consider `whereIn('commstatus', [$unavailableCheck, 1])` rather than having two equality checks.

Something like:

```
$users = User::where('role', '=', 2)
    ->whereIn('commstatus', [$unavailableCheck, 1])
    ->where("interface_art", '=', 1)
    ->orWhere("web_art", '=', 1)
    ->orWhere("illustration_art", '=', 1)
    ->orWhere("brush_art", '=', 1)
    ->orWhere("typography_art", '=', 1)
    ->orWhere("identity_art", '=', 1)
    ->orWhere("vector_art", '=', 1)
    ->orderBy($orderByString, 'desc')
    ->paginate(1);
```

Comment: Ah, I thought this worked but it didn't. The "role" and "commstatus" are only applied to the first where clause  (in this case interface art). All the other wheres don't have role 2 or commstatus applied to them.

Comment: The objective is to get an SQL clause that reads `WHERE \`role\`=2 AND \`commstatus\` IN ($unavailableCheck, 1) AND (\`interface_art\` = 1 OR \`web_art\` = 1 OR \`illustration_art\` = 1 OR ...)` Have you enabled database debug logging to see the query that you're actually getting?